# Как вернуть указатель на сгенерируемый обьект

Tags: c++, классы, указатели

как сделать чтобы функция generate() возвращала указатель на объект который она генерирует случайно

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class First_Name
{
private:
char first_name[40];

public:
virtual void vyvod()
{
    cout << "Введите фамилию" << endl;
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << first_name[0] << endl;
}

};

class Last_Name :public First_Name
{
private:
char second_name[40];

public:
void vyvod()
{
    cout << "Введите имя" << endl;
    cin >> second_name;
    cout << second_name[0] << endl;
}


};

class Middle_Name : public Last_Name
{
private:
char middle_name[40];

public:
void vyvod()
{
    cout << "Введите Отчество" << endl;
    cin >> middle_name;
    cout << middle_name[0] << endl;

}


};

class NullShape : public First_Name
{
public:
void vyvod() {};
};


int generate()
{
int i;
i = rand() % 4;
if (i == 0)
{
    First_Name base_ob;

}
else if (i == 1)
{
    Last_Name derrived_ob1;

}
else if (i == 2)
{
    Middle_Name derrived_ob2;
}
else if (i == 3)
{
    NullShape derrived_ob_3;
}
else
    cout << "IT was mistake" << endl;


}





int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    generate();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First_Name* generate()
{
    switch(rand() % 4)
    {
        case 0: return new First_Name;
        case 1: return new Last_Name;
        case 2: return new Middle_Name;
        case 3: return new NullShape;
    }
    return nullptr;   // Чтоб не шибко умный компилятор не ругался :)
}
```

Comment: Кто там минусанул - дайте свой ответ, интересно же у вас поучиться :)

Comment: а если возвращаемый указатель мне нужен в main чтобы определить его тип с помощью typeid()

Comment: Ну и используйте (определяйте), кто вам мешает? http://ideone.com/mhsNKW

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, принимая ответ ("птичка" слева).

Comment: можно вопрос почему тип функции generate First_Name*

Comment: потому что указатель на любой его наследник может неявно преобразовться в  такой указатель

Comment: А это единственный, по сути, вариант - общий знаменатель для них всех. Базовый класс - все остальные связаны с ним отношением *ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ*.

Comment: Кстати, просто интересно - а как вы себе представляли объявление функции, выводящей в зависимости от параметра разные типы?